# How to save Powershell script output as csv in Azure Git Repos after executing the script from Azure DevOps Release Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have a powershell script which generates a CSV report for some checks in Azure subscription.
This script is stored in Azure git and executed through Azure DevOps release pipeline using parameters for different subscriptions and resources. Output csv Filepath is also parameterized.
How can I save the output csv report with date-timestamp naming convention in Azure Git repo as part of the pipeline/script execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Pushes - Create** REST API from within your pipeline/task to add the file to your repo.

Sample request to add a text file:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pushes?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body

```
{
  "refUpdates": [
    {
      "name": "refs/heads/master",
      "oldObjectId": "8b67126d2500e28c771f82c9ddc292679978197c"
    }
  ],
  "commits": [
    {
      "comment": "Added task markdown file.",
      "changes": [
        {
          "changeType": "add",
          "item": {
            "path": "/tasks.md"
          },
          "newContent": {
            "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2",
            "contentType": "rawtext"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Check the [REST API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for other examples.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I save the output csv report with date-timestamp naming convention in Azure Git repo as part of the pipeline/script execution?

You can add a PowerShell task in Release Pipeline to run the Rest API: [Add a binary file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-binary-file)

To save the csv file with date-timestamp, you can use [Get-date script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.1#example-3--get-the-date-and-time-with-a--net-format-specifier) to get date.

Here is the full PowerShell sample:

```
$file= [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("filepath\a.csv")
$Base64file= [Convert]::ToBase64String($file)
echo $Base64file

$timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"


$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoid}/pushes?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = "
    {
  `"refUpdates`": [
    {
      `"name`": `"refs/heads/main`",
      `"oldObjectId`": `"Oldcommitid`"
    }
  ],
  `"commits`": [
    {
      `"comment`": `"Added new csv file.`",
      `"changes`": [
        {
          `"changeType`": `"add`",
          `"item`": {
            `"path`": `"b-$timestamp.csv`"
          },
          `"newContent`": {
            `"content`": `"$Base64file`",
            `"contentType`": `"base64encoded`"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
    }"


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json

echo $response
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bhargavi and Kevin for the response. sorry for the delay in reply on these solutions. What I'm trying is - I'm using a PSCustom object and appending the values of the required checks with all the other resource details. So how can I append and save this CSV file in ADO using PSCustomObject method.